# What does the process 'Main Thread' do?

Tags: process, banshee

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and listening to music using Banshee. At a certain point the graphics interface greys out and the application is unresponsive.

If I launch `ps`, the process list is monopolized by an application 'Main Thread' which is taking in excess of 100% of the CPU time and has been running for 20+ minutes as of now.

If I launch `pstree` the relevant excerpt is

```
    |-lightdm-+-Xorg-+-{InputThread}
    |         |      `-{disk_cache:0}
    |         |-lightdm-+-upstart-+-at-spi-bus-laun-+-dbus-daemon
    |         |         |         |                 |-{dconf worker}
    |         |         |         |                 |-{gdbus}
    |         |         |         |                 `-{gmain}
    |         |         |         |-at-spi2-registr-+-{gdbus}
    |         |         |         |                 `-{gmain}
    |         |         |         |-bamfdaemon-+-{dconf worker}
    |         |         |         |            |-{gdbus}
    |         |         |         |            `-{gmain}
    |         |         |         |-bash---Main Thread-+-{Finalizer}
    |         |         |         |                    |-7*[{Main Thread}]
    |         |         |         |                    |-{Timer-Scheduler}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{aqueue:src}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{audiosinkqueue:}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{dconf worker}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{flacparse8:sink}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{gdbus}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{gmain}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{mono}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{threaded-ml}
    |         |         |         |                    |-{typefind:sink}
    |         |         |         |                    `-{vis-queue:src}
```

Waht does this application 'Main Thread' do? 
And is there a way to avoid pre-emptively this way of things going stuck?

Comment: Related to this question: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193700/handling-mainthread-process-in-ubuntu

Comment: Related Bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1299573#

Comment: More related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263784/mainthread-unfamiliar-process-suddenly-showing-up-18-04