# Handling MainThread process in Ubuntu

Tags: process

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have noticed that from time to time a process named `MainThread` appears in my machine. I couldn't find out in which program it belong to though. Besides that I have noticed that if I kill it it doesn't seem to affect my machine. The reason I am interested in killing it is because it allocates some memory I need from my RAM (about half a GB).

So, I am wondering what's this process about and if it's OK to kill it (if I am missing something here I mean)?

Comment: I am facing this issue in Fedora 32 as well. This was not observed in earlier versions of Fedora. Maybe this is related to GNOME.

Comment: Related Question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184252/what-does-the-process-main-thread-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MainThread unfamiliar process suddenly showing up 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263784/mainthread-unfamiliar-process-suddenly-showing-up-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

I killed it and Firefox closed. I think it's part of Firefox.

Comment: Yes, and it re-appears when you restart Firefox