# MainThread unfamiliar process suddenly showing up 18.04

Tags: process, background-process

This morning, running `top`, I noticed a process I nave never seen before in my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop called `MainThread`, which was periodically using a lot of CPU . There was also an entry called `Privileged Cont`.

I recently installed nordvpn, but nordvpn support said the process is not theirs. Is this a new part of the operating system? Is it malware? It has never appeared in `top` on my laptop before, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

It is a change in recent firefox version (79+).

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1649010) about this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers there is a problem I encountered killing Firefox.

Previously I could use`sudo killall firefox`. Now that has no effect and `pgrep firefox` finds nothing.

For me to kill an unresponsive Firefox session I now need to use:

```
sudo killall /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Note above problem isn't limited to Ubuntu 18.04 as I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: xkill and a mouse click on the unresponsive window  save keystrokes :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I also saw that process and when I executed the kill  command, firefox it closed immediately. When I re-opened Firefox the process reappeared, but when I killed Firerox's WebExtensions process, MainThread significantly reduced memory usage.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that ManThread is the new process name for Firefox. I don't understand why Firefox would substitute a  cryptic name for an easily-understood one. In any case it's apparently not malware.